# Infinite loop in rock-paper-scissors loop game

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I am currently struggling to implement the while loop in my game as it always gives me an infinity loop. The idea is to continue the game except only when user types "-1"

```
    // declare variables
    int player, computer;
    int counter = 0;
    // player input
    System.out.println("Rock, Paper, Scissors!");
    System.out.print("Enter 0 for paper, 1 for Scissors, or 2 for Rock (-1 to quit) : ");
    player = sc.nextInt();
    while (player != -1) {

        // switch statement for player
        switch (player) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Player picks Paper");
            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Player picks Scissors");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Player picks Rock");
            break;
        case -1:
            System.exit(-1);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }

        // generate a random number for computer
        Random randomGen = new Random();
        computer = randomGen.nextInt(3);

        // switch statement for computer
        switch (computer) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Computer picks Paper");
            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Computer picks Scissors");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Computer picks Rock");
            break;
        default:
        }

        // output for each condition
        if (player == 2 && computer == 1)
            System.out.println("Player Wins!");
        else if (player == 1 && computer == 0)
            System.out.println("Player Wins!");
        else if (player == 0 && computer == 2)
            System.out.println("Player Wins!");
        else if (computer == 1 && player == 0)
            System.out.println("Computer Wins!");
        else if (player == 0 && computer == 2)
            System.out.println("Computer Wins!");
        else if (player == 1 && computer == 2)
            System.out.println("Computer Wins!");
        else
            System.out.println("Draw");
        sc.close();
    }
```

Comment: You’ve got this line duplicated: `else if(player == 0 && computer == 2)`. Should it have been `else if(computer == 0 && player == 2)` the second time?

Answer (score 1):

You never update your `player` value. Add `player = sc.nextInt()` to the end of the loop body. **Or**, do something like

```
int player;
while ((player = sc.nextInt()) != -1) {
```

**And**, I believe you should also remove the call to `sc.close();`

Comment: It’s good practice to close a `Scanner` after use — why wouldn’t you?

Comment: @OleV.V. OP is closing the `Scanner` **in** the loop body. Also, it likely wraps `System.in`, so closing that `Scanner` also closes the `System.in` *global*. Finally, I would prefer [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) over explicit closes (if that were not the case).

Comment: Agree it should be moved outside the loop. I too would use try-with-resources too for convenience (in this case I guess `sc` is declared outside the method; if so, try-with-resources is not possible, and the call to `close()` should go outisde of the method too for clarity).